# Does this count as using a hidden link?

Tags: html, css, text, hyperlink, hidden

I've been reading about hidden links and how they can be used to manipulate search results. I want to avoid doing anything deceptive while making a specific link a little more difficult to see. I understand using hidden links and text is viewed as deceptive and can get me into trouble, resulting in my website being placed lower in search results. Does my example below count as using a hidden link? The link will be visible and clickable by the user, and will change to a lighter blue when hovered over. Is there a better way to go about this?

```css
html {
  background-color: #111;
}

#everythinglink {
  padding-left: 1vw;
  color: #112;
  display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:30px;
}
#everythinglink:hover {
  color: #0038FF;
}
```

```html
<a href="everything.html" id="everythinglink"><p>Everything</p></a>
```

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this link's color? In this case your link is just terrible for accessibility since it has pretty much the same colour as the background — nobody using sight to navigate your website will be able to see this. You'll want a contrasting colour, check out [Contrast Ratio](https://contrast-ratio.com/) to get an idea. In your case, your link should probably be `#fff`.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen For fun. Don't want it to be easily accessible, just legal by all browsers standards, especially google.

Comment: @guyw accessibility is always important in **any** website you make, and accessibility will always help in Google search  results (probably). Besides, it's a standard as well.

Comment: @guyw avoid hidden links, search engines don't like it, they'll put you at the bottom of search results. They think you're trying to fool them! They have robots, and they can detect this.